# $f\times\text{id}$ is closed for a closed map $f$ with $f^{-1}(y)$ compact $\forall y\in Y$

Tags: general-topology, product-space, closed-map

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a map between topological spaces such that
 $f$ is closed and $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact in $X$ for every $y\in Y$.

Now I have to show that the map $f\times\text{id}:X\times T \rightarrow Y\times T$ is closed for every topological space $T$.

I don't really know how to start here. Therefore any hint or advice is appreciated!

Comment: This is probably equivalent to your definition, but a proper map is usually defined to be a map such that the preimage of a compact set is compact. **edit :** In fact, these definitions are equivalent provided $Y$ is locally compact and Hausdorff.

Comment: @OlivierRoche I thought that this is the case, but what I've written is what we defined in the lecture.

Comment: It is not really equivalent in general (see my edit)

Comment: Ok, I editet the question. Thank you.

Comment: Does "compact" include Hausdorff?

Comment: No, compact just means the "usual" covering property.

Comment: I think that [this criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753649/what-is-a-good-criterion-to-quickly-show-a-map-is-or-is-not-closed) might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this very statement in page 90 of the book *Topology and Groupoids* by R. Brown.

The proof basically show that the complement of each $(f\times{id})(C)$ for $C$ closed in $X\times T$ is open in $Y\times T$ and relies on the following "tube lemma" (also shown in the book).

**Lemma.** Let $X,Y$ topological spaces and let $A\subset X,B\subset Y$ be two compact subsets. Let furthermore $W$ be an open subset of $X\times Y$ containing $A\times B$. Then there are open sets $U\supset A, V\supset B$ such that $A\times B\subset U\times V\subset W$.